# jquery ui datepicker go to today button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

i need my calendar to go to the current date when **[today]** button is clicked, so that the user can get to the current day when browsing my calendar.

for example the current month is *feb 2013*
and the user is browsing on the *dec 2015* page of the calendar  when he clicks the **[today]** button it will automatically return to the current days page of the calendar which is 
*feb 2013*.

i'am using

> jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js

as a plugin for my calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
function TodaysDate() {
 var currentTime = new Date()
 var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
 var day = currentTime.getDate()
 var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

 return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

$("#btnToday").click(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  $(target).datepicker('setDate', TodaysDate()); 
}
```

Where `target` is your date picker control ID.

Answer (score 8):

The jQuery UI Datepicker has functionality built into it for this.

See this: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```